# Getting modified image metadata from iCloud Photo Library

Tags: ios, image, uikit, photokit

I'm currently retrieving images (and associated metadata) from the iCloud Photo Library using the Photos framework (PhotoKit) and the following code:

```
PHAsset *asset = ...;

PHImageRequestOptions *options = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat; // ignored by requestImageDataForAsset

self.requestID = [self.imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
    if (imageData) {
        NSDictionary *metadata = nil;

        CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
        if (sourceRef) {
            CFDictionaryRef dictionaryRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, NULL);
            if (dictionaryRef) {
                metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)dictionaryRef;
                CFRelease (dictionaryRef);
            }
            CFRelease (sourceRef);
        }

        NSLog("metadata = %@", metadata);

        self.requestID = PHInvalidAssetResourceDataRequestID;
    }
}];
```

The problem I'm having is that the metadata that's returned is from the original file. It does not contain any modifications for title, description, or keywords done with the Photos app (these items are stored in the {IPTC} category.)

The header documentation for `-requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler` states that `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent` can be used to retrieve the adjusted *rendered image* but this doesn't seem to apply to adjustments to the metadata.

Is there another way to get the modified metadata from the Photos framework? Customers who use the Photos app on the Mac to add titles, descriptions, and keywords to their images would like to see the results on iOS.

Comment: I've filed a Radar about this issue: http://www.openradar.me/27333690